# jQuery .click() not working, while other jQuery functions do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I'm trying to create a Greasemonkey userscript that will click on one of the divs on the page. They don't refer to a link, more likely a JS/Ajax function, but I can't tell if that is true. So the problem is that this script does nothing. Jquery functions like .remove() work, but .click() does not. What exactly is wrong? I tried searching questions on this topic, but none seemed to help.

Code on page:

```
        <div style="display: block;" class="oitm">
            <div class="item">
            <img class="smallimg" src="">
    </div></div>
 <div style="display: none;" class="oitm">
            <div class="item">
            <img class="smallimg" src="">
    </div></div>
```

My code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
       var reqItem = $('.oitm[style*="display: block"]');
      $(reqItem).click();
});
```

Please note, that

```
reqItem.click();
```

does not work as well.

*Upd: there is also a jquery code, but it's placed outside of the elements I posted above (#offer.left is an element where a clicked item is supposed to show up after it's clicked).*

```
<script>
$("#offer").on( "click", ".item", function() {
    if ($('#offer .left').children().size() < 9) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo('#offer .left');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the click handler that you want to be invoked, a jQuery click handler?  Or is it registered with `.addEventListener()` or with `onclick=xxx`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to click a div tag ?

Comment: @jfriend00 I just discovered that it's a jQuery script in a <script> tag. I will try to add the code.

Comment: Wrap jQuery `$().on(..)` into `$(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/5zddqx28/ .

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.oitm[style*="display: block"]').click(function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });

    var reqItem = $('.oitm[style*="display: block"]');

    $(reqItem).click();

});
```

Make sure you put onclick listener **before** your `.click();` call.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a GreaseMonkey situation which very well may be different than your simple example.

Comment: This does not match the question.  Note that the target page fires `.on()` for `.item`s.  This code currently has a .`click()` set for **`.oitm`**. ... [Fixing that error, breaks this answer's approach](http://jsfiddle.net/5zddqx28/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine:

```
<div style="display: block;" class="oitm">
      <div class="item">Top Div
           <img class="smallimg" src="">
      </div>
</div>
 <div style="display: none;" class="oitm">
      <div class="item">Bottom Div
            <img class="smallimg" src="">
      </div>
</div>

$( document ).ready(function() {

    var reqItem = $('.oitm[style*="display: block"]').click();

    $(reqItem).on('click',function(){ alert('I was clicked'); });

    $(reqItem).click();

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xnLoumt/

Comment: Keep in mind this is a GreaseMonkey situation which very well may be different than your simple example.

Comment: Indeed, I second that.

Comment: The `.on()` is wrong in this answer.  It needs to fire on `.item` to match the question.

Answer (score 0):

A selector that looks at the style attribute only works for browsers that format the style in exactly that way, or leaves the attribute in the original format when the code is parsed. You can use the `:visible` selector to find the visible elements:

```
var reqItem = $('.oitm:visible');
```